# how do i implement creating mp3s on the fly?

Tags: audio, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sox

I have a need to create mp3s on the fly by converting a bunch of smaller wav files and stringing them together. I use an open source command line tool called Sox to create the mp3s. http://sox.sourceforge.net/ I'm using Amazon aws, and I can use s3 to store all the wav files as they're uploaded and make them available for streaming. The way I was going to implement it is:

Uploading:
Simply put the wav files on s3

Creating mp3:
Check to see if each wav file exists on the webserver, if it doesnt, download it.
Then do the media processing on the webserver and send the mp3 to the client.
Store the mp3 on s3 for later retrieval.

My question is whether I need to do anything special in order to implement this effectively. Am I headed for a dead end?

Answer (score 0):

I've built something that does exactly this.  It's the Radio Reddit Media Transcoder, and is open source.

https://bitbucket.org/radioreddit/radio-reddit-media-transcoder

The S3 functionality isn't built-in yet, but I'm adding it soon.  In the mean time, it can be modified slightly for your needs.  Basically, this server reads your original media files in whatever format, runs them through an external codec (like FFmpeg or Sox) and streams the output to clients.

This method does work well for MP3, but you do need to be careful about formats that you cannot stream straight from the encoder.  Anything in an MP4 container needs to be written to disk first because some of the file at the beginning needs to be written after the rest of the file was written.  I'm planning on having a mode where these files are written to scratch space first before sending off to the client, but this is not yet done.  In any case, for MP3, you can use it as-is.